# Is there a way to output the closure type of an extended lambda from NVCC?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

I'm trying to port parts of a large project of mine to CUDA/HIP and have been disappointed with the [countless restrictions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#notes-on-host-device-lambdas) that there are on the use of extended lambdas. I encountered a nasty bug when trying to evaluate `std::invocable` on a device lambda, where the result depended on the execution space of the lambda. With the many counter-intuitive statements made about restirctions on extended lambdas, it seems as though it would be helpful to view the source of the closure type generated by the CUDA compiler when handling `__device___` and `__host__ __device__` lambdas. Is this possible to do?

Comment: What is the bug with std::invocable?

Comment: For issues with extended lambdas [this discussion](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/issues/779#event-8680507248) might be of interest, as well as [`cuda::proclaim_return_type`](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/extended_api/functional/proclaim_return_type.html) from libcu++.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor I was passing a lambda as a template parameter to a function which, in host code, check one of two cases of invocability using std::invocable. This works well usually, but with a __device__ lambda, std::invocable was errantly returning true for all argument types.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, this was simple to do, using the `--keep` option with nvcc and inspecting the file `*.cudafe1.cpp` file.